# jquery each json create bootstrap carousel multi image item

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I use this code to create a carousel item single image

```
$.getJSON('index.php?callback=?','&option=com_jea&task=properties.test&format=json',function(res){
var carousel = $('<div/>',{ 'class': 'carousel-inner'})
{  
    $.each(res, function(i, data) {
    var item = $('<div/>',{ 'class': 'item'})
    $('<div class="span2">'+res[i].My Image+'</div>').appendTo(item );
    item.appendTo(carousel);
})
carousel.appendTo('#myCarousel');}})
```

html

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item">my image</div>
<div class="item">my image</div></div>
```

I would like to enter a default number of images inside of item like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item"><ul><li>my image</li><li>my image</li></ul></div>
<div class="item"><ul><li>my image</li><li>my image</li></ul></div>
<div class="item"><ul><li>my image</li><li>my image</li></ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working?

Comment: it works but I would like to create <ul> inside the item class with a defined number of images